# Can I still publish a paper in a journal after it has already been assigned a DOI through Zenodo or ResearchGate?

Tags: publications

Zenodo and ResearchGate can assign a DOI to an article. After publishing an article on Zenodo or ResearchGate with a DOI, if the article is good, will the article still be accepted for publication by peer-reviewed journals?  Assume that the journal in question allows green open access (i.e., posting of a preprint on a public site).

Comment: That depends what you mean by "publishing". Perhaps you could clarify exactly what problem you're facing that prompts this question?

(the answers to your second and third paragraphs are: (a) Yes, you can upload to all these places; and (b) whether it's the appropriate action depends on what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: Later, I want to send my article to a peer-review green journal for publication.

Comment: Is there anything against using arxiv or similar platforms? High-ranked journals are often okay with accepting papers that have been published as pre-print there. However, some journals are quite strictly against sharing work on platforms such as ResearchGate after peer-review/publication - it feels like they might decide against reviewing papers that have been uploaded to RG before submission as well.

Comment: The existence of a DOI is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

To "publish" something really just means "make it available to others". So, there are many ways to publish something: You can strive to get it accepted in the most prestigious journals of your field, or you can just put it on your website -- strictly speaking, both qualify as "publishing". Putting an article on Zenodo, ResearchGate, or arXiv is closer to the latter than the former; the fact that some of them can give you a DOI really just means that you make it easier for others to find and reference what you uploaded.

From a practical perspective, the difference between all of your options is how much vetting and endorsement the locations where you publish provide for your work. Academic journals *review* your article, and this provides a level of endorsement that lets others trust that what you published is useful and correct. On the other hand, putting an article on a web site or ResearchGate involves no vetting and, consequently, does not bestow on you the *prestige* that comes with the vetting. If you wanted to use your "publications" as part of a job application, it is this *prestige* you want, and consequently, putting your work on a website of your own will not be enough.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the best way is to submit my manuscript to a peer-review journal. My question is that after putting an article on Zenodo and ResearchGate with DOI, the article will still be accepted by a peer-review green journal for publication if the article is good?

Comment: Strictly speaking, journals typically require you to assign copyright to them before publication, and that would prevent you from publishing the work in any other way. In practice, they often turn a blind eye to pre-publication on arXiv, researchgate, or your own website, even though strictly speaking you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with the individual journal(s) you are interested in eventually submitting to. In my experience, most have posted policies somewhere in their "instructions for authors" sections.

Most likely the presence of a DOI is completely irrelevant, but there isn't a general rule on what publishers will consider prior publication.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I just found that Zenodo is a preprint server.